# Applying a value offset through a list in a way that resembles a sine wave (eases in and out)

Tags: python, trigonometry

First off, sorry for the title gore, I'm unsure of how to describe what I'm after more elegantly.

Basically, I'm trying to create a function that I can pass a list of numbers to, an offset value to, and have that function return that list with the offset being applied in an easing-in, easing-out manner, [similar to a sine wave.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0zMu.png)

So for example, say I give this function a list of 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 and an offset of 10. I'd want it to return something like 0, 2, 5, 8.5, 10, 8.5, 5, 2, 0. How would I go about that?

Comment: If it really ramps up and down like a sine wave, then the largest changes will be at the ends, where the value of sine is closest to zero.  So the numbers would be significantly different from what you have in your example.

Comment: If you are putting the elements from a list into a sin function, and each element is calculated independently from the others, why not just take a subset of the inputted list? The length of the subset then depends on the offet value.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got any ideas how to approach this problem yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do exactly what you asked for:

```
import math

d = [0] * 9
offset = 10

dlen = len(d)
r = [d[i] + offset * math.sin(i * math.pi / (dlen - 1))
     for i in range(dlen)]

print d
print r
```